# Use JMeter HTTP Proxy to record JSON over HTTP request from not-a-browser client

Tags: http, proxy, jmeter, load-testing

I have a client program running locally in iPhone emulator and local server written in Java. Client talks to server with JSON over HTTP requests. Now I am trying to record a client session http requests with JMeter to use them as a base to load-test server.

The problem is client requests do not go throw JMeter proxy. Client gets 501 "Method not implemented" (it is not because of https, I am using http). There is nothing in JMeter log about the request, and obviously nothing gets recorded in JMeter and the request doesn't reach the server.

There is well-described steps to setup JMeter proxy to record request from a browser, but my client programm is not a browser. Though JSON over HTTP is widely adopted approach, I could not find anything on the web about recording such requests with JMeter. I understand I need to do on the client the same thing browser does when proxying request and what I've found about it is that I need to set Host header to server's host and port, but that did not work and I cannot see how is it related to 501 error client gets.

If someone can explain what should be done on client or how to configure JMeter to let it know where to proxy client's requests or link any manual explaining that, it would be great help. I've been searching for solution for a few hours already and had no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my question and the answer I got below:

[Use Jmeter proxy to record HTTP calls from iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077373/use-jmeter-proxy-to-record-http-calls-from-ios-simulator)

In short:
With this tutorial you can record calls from your Android device:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy

For make same thing with iPhone, do the following steps:

Mac configuration:

system preferences -> Network -> Advanced.. -> Proxies -> check "Web Proxy (HTTP) ->in "Web Proxy Server" field, type your IP (http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Mac), and choose available port (I using 8080) ->ok -> Apply

iPhone configuration:

Settings -> WiFi -> choose same wifi you use with your Mac -> press on it again to go to it's details -> scroll down ->In HTTP proxy, choose Manual -> server = your mac IP you found earlier -> port = the port you chosen (maybe 8080)

Now You can start recording all "iPhone network out" using jmeter recording controller