# Use Jmeter proxy to record HTTP calls from iOS simulator

Tags: ios, proxy, ios-simulator, jmeter, test-plan

Is there any way to record http calls from native app that installed on iOS simulator, or real device ?

My main goal is to build test plan by playing the app and recording the calls.

Any help or creative idea is welcome :)

Thanks, Yossi

Comment: Did you try to use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder ?

Comment: Hi olyv, Yes I did try, but it works only for browsers, not for other applications, thanks :)

Comment: I recorded only requests from mobile (Android) browser but here http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy is said that it could be done also for native applications

Comment: Thanks @olyv, this link was the one that helped me to record the calls from my iphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a real device it's very easy. Use the Wifi on the device (airplane mode) and set HTTP Proxy to point to your computer.

Here is a complete webinar with step by step details on recording iOS traffic with JMeter's proxy:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZFch4B5Ivc
(technical stuff starts at 13 minutes in)

Here is a blog with details for Android (it's the same idea for as for iOS):
http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy

Comment: Thanks :) I now able to test on a real device

Comment: Do you know how to test it on iOS simulator?